# Error in reading values of UITextfields

Tags: swift

I'm having trouble reading the values from a textfield. Every time I type in this line `let username = UsernameTextField.text` I get an error saying "Cannot use instance member 'UsernameTextField' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

Here is the full code:

```
import UIKit

class SignInViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var UsernameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var PasswordTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var LogInButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), for: .default)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
        navigationController?.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        // Remove Autocorrection Type
        UsernameTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
        PasswordTextField.autocorrectionType = .no
        PasswordTextField.textContentType = UITextContentType("")
        //Next button takes user to the next textfield
        UsernameTextField.delegate = self
        PasswordTextField.delegate = self
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        if textField == UsernameTextField{
            PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

        } else if textField == PasswordTextField {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
        }
        return true
    }

    let username = UsernameTextField.text
}
```

Comment: Because that line "is lost", it's "nowhere" not in a method?

Comment: What do you mean by not in a method?

Comment: You have that line of code outside of the method curly brackets but inside of the class curly brackets

Comment: It needs to be inside of a method (or function) not stand alone in the class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what you have, the call to set the text is NOT in a function.

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == UsernameTextField{
        PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()

    } else if textField == PasswordTextField {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    return true
}

let username = UsernameTextField.text // THIS IS NOT IN A FUNCTION
```

Move it here:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    if textField == UsernameTextField{
        PasswordTextField.becomeFirstResponder()
    } else if textField == PasswordTextField {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    let username = UsernameTextField.text // THIS IS NOW IN A FUNCTION    
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Any chance that you have a subclass of `UITextField` called `UsernameTextField`?
If so, it might be referencing the class instead of the instance.

I would recommend keeping variables' names camelCased. Makes it easier to differentiate between variables and classes.

If this is the convention you use, you might also try using

`let name = self.UsernameTextField.text`

EDIT:

It seems that this line is outside the function scope.
Should move it before the closing `}`.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
let username = UsernameTextField.text
```

is in the scope of your class definition, not inside the scope of a method. Therefore this constitutes a property initialization which is run upon construction of an instance of the class. You're trying to initialize the member variable username using ANOTHER member variable (UsernameTextField). This, of course, cannot work, since the object has to be fully initialized before any members can be read.

Did you mean to put the line inside the scope of the method textFieldShouldReturn?

Answer (score 0):

As the error suggests "UsernameTextField" is an instance member which means it does not get instantiated until the class is instantiated (as opposed to static members) which means that by the time your line is compiled which is before the class is instantiated, that member does not exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

You have to move you constants and place them right under "return true"